# How to query posts by category with the_title();

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Im have a little issue querying a custom post type by category using the_title();

The reason why im doing it like this is because the title is the same as the category name.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'Testimonials', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category_name' =>the_title());
```

However with this im not getting a thing i have also tried this:

```
$title = the_title();
$args = array('post_type' => 'Testimonials', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category_name' =>$title);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the declaration of the function `the_title()`, it prints the title, if the third parameter `$echo` is set to `TRUE` which is the default:

```
/**
 * Display or retrieve the current post title with optional content.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $before Optional. Content to prepend to the title.
 * @param string $after Optional. Content to append to the title.
 * @param bool $echo Optional, default to true.Whether to display or return.
 * @return null|string Null on no title. String if $echo parameter is false.
 */
function the_title($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true) {
    $title = get_the_title();

    if ( strlen($title) == 0 )
        return;

    $title = $before . $title . $after;

    if ( $echo )
        echo $title;
    else
        return $title;
}
```

So either you use `the_title( '', '', FALSE )` or even better `get_the_title()` because it makes the code better readable:

```
$title = get_the_title();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Testimonials',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'category_name' => $title
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the whole concept of this question is a little bit wrong. The thing about custom post types is that they don't have categories like regular posts. They have taxonomies and terms. In fact regular categories are also a taxonomy for regular posts.

So answering your questions, you need to know the name of the taxonomy first.
The simple way is to hover over taxonomy menu item in WordPress dashboard using Chrome. The taxonomy will appear in a lower left corner of the screen. See screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp38u.jpg

Then, when you know the taxonomy name, you can do something like this:

```
$term = $post->post_name;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Testimonials',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy_name',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term
            )
        )
);
```

But this thing will only work if the name of the term you are trying get is the same  with the slug of the current post you are on.

Comment: With `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` you can add the default category taxonomy for any object type.